# Use custom path for naked main domain (except path) in apche2

Tags: apache, apache2

I have the following apache config file

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName example.io
    ServerAlias *.*

    Alias /static /var/www/user/master/workbench/workbench/static
    DocumentRoot /var/www/user/master/workbench/workbench/static

    # Redirect naked URL to the specified URL
    # RedirectMatch ^/$ http://other-example.io

    # Load custom index page as homepage
    AliasMatch ^/$ /var/www/user/master/workbench/scnv_home

    WSGIDaemonProcess example.io   processes=1 threads=5 python-path=/var/www/user/master/workbench:/home/ubuntu/.virtualenv/app/lib/python2.7/site-packages/
    WSGIProcessGroup example.io
    WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/user/master/workbench/workbench/wsgi.py

    <Directory /var/www/user/master/workbench/workbench/static >
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
        AllowOverride All
    </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

The domain is used to access **Django** site using **WSGI** and `RedirectMatch` configuration option is used to redirect user to some other domain.

```
https://example.io        -> Redirects to http://other-example.io
https://example.io/path    # Served by Django
```

Now I want to show a custom `index.html` page instead of redirecting user to some other domain.

For that I tried to use the `AliasMatch` option to point to the directory where `index.html` file exists, but it is still being served by **Django** and gives **404** page by Django.

**How can I setup apache to serve request by `Django` if url has path, otherwise load custom index page?**

Comment: I want to know from you that do you use SSL?

Comment: What do you want to know?

Comment: I want to know from you that do you use SSL?

Comment: Yes, I do use SSL.

Answer (score 0):

`<VirtualHost _default_:443>`

`#JkMount /* worker1`

`DocumentRoot "/var/www/html"`

`ProxyPass /error/404.html !`

`ErrorDocument 404 /error/404.html`

`ProxyPass / "ajp://localhost:443/`

`ProxyPassReverse / "ajp://localhost:443/`

`ServerName yourdomain.com:443`

Try to use above code in your `ssl.conf` file hope that will help you...!!!!

Comment: do the modification in above config as per your requirement like file path Document root, Error document, proxypass.